# MySQL: Assigning to a local variable in a select

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Is it possible to use `SELECT local_variable := expression FROM [...]` syntax in MySQL with ***local*** variables as opposed to ***session*** variables?

This works:

```
DELIMITER //   

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_local_variables;
CREATE PROCEDURE test_local_variables()
  BEGIN    
    select @last_name, @last_name := SPECIFIC_NAME from information_schema.ROUTINES limit 10;
  END;

//
DELIMITER ;
```

However, I can't get MySQL to take this:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_local_variables;
CREATE PROCEDURE test_local_variables()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE last_name VARCHAR(18);
    SET last_name = 'first_value';

    select last_name, last_name := SPECIFIC_NAME from information_schema.ROUTINES limit 10;
  END;

//
DELIMITER ;
```

It fails with the error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ':= SPECIFIC_NAME from information_schema.ROUTINES
>   limit 10;   END' at line 6

I'd really like to get this working with local variables.  Thanks!

Comment: `SELECT foo INTO varname`, basically.

Comment: Doing that gave:

mysql> call test_local_variables;
ERROR 1222 (21000): The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: SELECT SPECIFIC_NAME into last_name; should work. If you want to return last name as well you need to do that separately